# How can i make nav bar highlighted in angular2?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I want to make navbar active for this i am using css but when i am going to refresh page active tab is going to remove how can i do this in angular 2?

```
 HTML:--


<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-top "
                    *ngFor="let menu of menus">
                    <li><a href="" (click)="goToPage($event)">{{menu}}
                    </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

css:--

```
navigation a:FOCUS {
    box-shadow: 0 -5px 0 -4px #eee;
    color: #ffffff;
    width:30%
}

.navigation a:HOVER {
    box-shadow: 0 -5px 0 -4px #eee;
    color: #ffffff;
    width:30%
}
```

Comment: How do you go to a particular page? using which functionality? are you using angular router?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `routerLinkActive` to add some css to your active route, for example:

```
<a routerLink="login" routerLinkActive="active-class">Login</a>
```

Comment: Here in place of login i am using some dynamic property like<a>{{menu}}</a> is that a correct way to bind this routerLink="{{menu}}"?please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-top" *ngFor="let menu of menus">
     <li>
         <a routerLink="menu"  routerLinkActive="active">{{menu}}</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: not getting any value on html or also in console through this:-- <a routerLink="menu"  routerLinkActive="active">{{menu}}</a>

Comment: seriously? just try `<li>{{menu}}</li>`. do you even get any value in {{menu}}?

Comment: yes than i am getting value but when i am going to add routerLink="menu"  routerLinkActive="active" it's gone.

Comment: yes error is like that:---EXCEPTION: Error in ./Menu class Menu - inline template:18:64

Comment: As of now, i'd suggest you to try with static route n check whether solution works. Eg. `routerLink="/contacts"`

Comment: Its working when i am adding like this :--<a [routerLink]="['/contact']"routerLinkActive="active">Contact</a> but when i am going to refresh page its gone.